# Inheritance of styles from the main graph to subgraphs in Galaxybase graph database

Tags: graph-databases

I'm using Galaxybase graph database, and I have encountered an issue regarding the inheritance of styles.
Specifically, I have set up styles for the main graph, but when I retrieve subgraph data based on the subgraph task ID by concatenating the URL, the subgraph does not inherit the styles from the main graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Galaxybase styles are user-specific. The embedded graph display service has a dedicated default user named "embedded" with the password "123456". If you want to set a style, please log in to the visualization platform using this user account and configure the desired style for the corresponding graph. Afterwards, you can retrieve the subgraph data to display the corresponding style.